# How to search for multiple multi-word phrases in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some JSON data converted into a Pandas DataFrame. I am looking to find all columns whose string content matches a list of multi word phrases.

I am working with a massive amount of Twitter JSON data [already downloaded for public use](https://archive.org/details/twitterstream) (so Twitter API usage is not applicable). This JSON is converted into a Pandas DataFrame. One of the columns available is, `text` which the body of the tweet. An example is

```
We’re kicking off the first portion of a citywide traffic calming project to make residential streets more safe & pedestrian-friendly, next week!

Tuesday, July 30 at 10:30 AM
Nautilus Drive and 42 Street
```

I want to be able to have a list of phrases, `phrases = ["We're kicking off", "we're starting", "we're initiating"]` and do something like `pd[pd['text'].str.contains(phrases)]]` to ensure that I can obtain pandas DataFrame rows whose `text` column contains one of the phrases.

This is perhaps asking too much, but ideally I would also be able to match something like  `phrases = ["(We're| we are) kicking off", "(we're | we are) starting", "(we're| we are) initiating"]`

Comment: please post a sample data and expected output too

Comment: @anky_91 I just updated!

Answer (score 0):

Make a list with keywords or phrases you want to match, i have put on logic for perfect match, you can change it by changing regex. Also it will capture by which keywords was the text caught.
Here is the code -

```
for i in range(len(mustkeywords)):
    for index in range(len(text)):
        result = re.search(r'\s*\b'+mustkeywords[i]+r'\W\s*', text[index])

        if result:
            commentlist.append(text[index])
            keywordlist.append(mustkeywords[i])

tempmustkeywordsdf=pd.DataFrame(columns={"Comments"},data=commentlist) #temp df for keywords
tempmustkeywordsdf["Keywords"]=keywordlist #adding keywords column to this df
```

Here mustkeywords is a list that contains your phrases or keywords
.text is a string that contains all the data/phrases that you want to check keywords into.
and tempmustkeywordsdf is that contains matched strings and keywords that matched them.
I hope this helps.